# Shapeless lenses usage with a string definition

Tags: scala, shapeless, lenses

I would like use shapeless lenses to access value of the case class field by a String definition.

I know this code works.

```
case class Test(id: String, calc: Long)
val instance = Test("123232", 3434L)

val lens = lens[Test] >> 'id

val valueOfFieldId = lens.get(instance)
```

But what I am trying to do is:

```
 val fieldName = "id"

 val lens = lens[Test] >> fieldName.witness
//I typed .witness because it was expecting a witness (if I am not wrong)

 val valueOfFieldId = lens.get(instance)
```

But with this code, I am getting this error.

Could not find implicit value for parameter mkLens: shapeless.MkFieldLens[A$A148.this.Test,A$A148.this.str.type]
def get$$instance$$lll = lll;/* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */ lazy val lens = lens[Test] >> str.witness

Is it possible to get the value of case class field with a String definition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use `Symbol` (`'id`) here rather than `String` (`"id"`).

Creating `Symbol` from `String`

`Symbol(fieldName)`

is runtime operation and Shapeless operates in compile time.

Why can't you use symbols?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to use it like this:

val fieldName = "id"
val lens = lens[Test] >> Symbol(fieldName)
val valueOfFieldId = lens.get(instance)

I am getting this error. 
Expression scala.Symbol.apply(A$A10.this.str) does not evaluate to a constant or a stable reference value
def get$$instance$$lll = lll;/* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */ lazy val lens = lens[Test] >> Symbol(str)


But this one works.
val lens = lens[Test] >> Symbol("id")

I would like to read it from a variable.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to do something like https://github.com/jeremyrsmith/shapeless-applied (examples: https://github.com/jeremyrsmith/shapeless-applied/blob/master/src/test/scala/applied/AppliedSpec.scala ). They define macros `String => String`, `Symbol => Symbol` and you need `String => Symbol`.