# Using `String` instead of `Symbol` in `LabelledGeneric` etc

Tags: scala, shapeless

As indicated in both the *Type Astronaut's Guide to shapeless* (footnote 4), and 
 Gitter  [April 5, 2018 3:35 PM](https://gitter.im/milessabin/shapeless?at=5ac6342927c509a774de7797), future versions of shapeless may change the key constraint of `KeyTag` (and therefore `FieldType`) from `Symbol` to `String`.

I am therefore trying to use string literals (supported in typelevel scala compiler, and also recent 2.12 releases with the `-Yliteral-types` flag) as the key type in my fields, to future-proof my code.

However, at present, all typeclasses using labels, particularly `LabelledGeneric` return FieldTypes with `Symbols` as keys. For instance:

```scala
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> case class Foo(bar : Int)
defined class Foo

scala> LabelledGeneric[Foo]
res0: shapeless.LabelledGeneric[Foo]{type Repr = Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("bar")],Int] :: shapeless.HNil} = shapeless.LabelledGeneric$$anon$1@56635171
                                                                                !!! ^^^^^^ !!!
```

So I'm trying to write an instance that converts `LabelledGenerix.Aux.Repr` between `FieldType[S <: Symbol,_]` and `FieldType[S <: String,_]`, in the hope that in a future release, when the library macros/typeclasses are updated to return `String`s, I will be able to simply remove that. I'm struggling to achieve this though. Essentially this boils down to implementing

```scala
      def syFldToStrFld[St <: String, Sy <: Symbol, T](syFld : FieldType[Sy,T])(implicit syWit : Witness.Aux[Sy]) : FieldType[St,T] =
        (syWit.value.name : String) ->> (syFld : T)
```

Which results in

```
[error] : Expression (syWit.value.name: String) does not evaluate to a constant or a stable reference value
```

Is there any way to work around this, at *compile time*? Or are there any other ways one could use `String`s as keys in shapeless and have them interop with all the built-in library methods e.g. `LabelledGeneric`, `Record`, etc.?

Comment: Similar discussion was recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418767/shapeless-lenses-usage-with-a-string-definition/50426537#50426537). I guess this can be done with macros. Maybe this can be similar to https://github.com/jeremyrsmith/shapeless-applied (examples: https://github.com/jeremyrsmith/shapeless-applied/blob/master/src/test/scala/applied/AppliedSpec.scala ). They define macros `String => String`, `Symbol => Symbol` and we need `String => Symbol`.

Comment: Stick with Symbols until I release a version of shapeless which uses Strings for LabelledGeneric.

Comment: Hey @Miles, has this happened?  If not any ideas when it will?

Comment: @JacksonKelley not yet, but expect some movement soon.