# How to access case class fields using a variable in shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I want to do something like this

```
case class Dog(name :String, breed : String)

val dg = Dog("ABC", "Husky")
```

At run time I want to get the case class field value through a variable
Below, `"name"` would be dynamically calculated driven from another input

```
val str = "'" + "name"
val witn = Witness(Symbol(str))
```

It fails with  Expression

> scala.Symbol.apply(str) does not evaluate to a constant or a stable value

I am not sure how this should be resolved. If it can be resolved

Appreciate all help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using `String` instead of `Symbol` in `LabelledGeneric` etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526509/using-string-instead-of-symbol-in-labelledgeneric-etc)

Guess it has been asked and answered above. 
there is no support for String yet. Waiting for the release that has it!